# How to get records only with payment is one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
    select transactions.*, MONTH(transactions.created_at) AS mth, clients.payment_type from result_test

    LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.transaction_id = result_test.transaction_id

    LEFT JOIN clients ON clients.id = result_test.client_id AND clients.payment_type = 1

    WHERE transactions.center_id = 202 
AND transactions.in_act = 1 AND transactions.status = 1 
AND date(transactions.created_at) >= '2019-06-04 08:16:07' 
AND date(transactions.created_at) <= '2019-12-31 08:16:07'
```

I have tried to get only records where `clients.payment_type`, but now I get two rows.

Should I use group by or having?

[image]

Comment: For me works this: `HAVING clients.payment_type > 0;`

Comment: You can just change the `LEFT JOIN` on `clients` to a `JOIN`.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need  only matching values  (not null) then   use inner join instead  of left  join  for clients

```
select transactions.*, MONTH(transactions.created_at) AS mth, clients.payment_type 
from result_test
LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.transaction_id = result_test.transaction_id 
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = result_test.client_id 
    AND clients.payment_type = 1 
WHERE transactions.center_id = 202 AND transactions.in_act = 1 
    AND transactions.status = 1 
    AND date(transactions.created_at) >= '2019-06-04 08:16:07' 
    AND date(transactions.created_at) <= '2019-12-31 08:16:07'
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `clients.payment_type = 1` to `where` clause.

```
select transactions.*, MONTH(transactions.created_at) AS mth, clients.payment_type 
from result_test
LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.transaction_id = result_test.transaction_id 
LEFT JOIN clients ON clients.id = result_test.client_id 
WHERE transactions.center_id = 202 
    AND transactions.in_act = 1 
    AND transactions.status = 1 
    AND date(transactions.created_at) >= '2019-06-04 08:16:07' 
    AND date(transactions.created_at) <= '2019-12-31 08:16:07'
    AND clients.payment_type = 1
```